# How to run the next line of code without waiting for page to load after click () java selenium on Chrome?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, click, load

After a page is loaded, I will `click()` an element. Once the click is performed, I want the next command to be performed. How can I do that?

I have two conditions:

1. The next line of command has nothing to do with the page being loaded.
2. The page needed to be continued to load.

Example:

```
Driver.findeelementby("SignIn").click();
System.out.println("Random Done");
```

After the click, the page takes 30-40 seconds to load. So, I want the o/p to be displayed as "Random Done" immediately after the click is performed and not to wait for those 30-40 seconds.

After a minute or so, I will perform the actions to the page loaded manually.

*Hope I'm not confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no such way and the only best possible option is to use the multithreading concept in case if we're looking to perform parallel tests on different URLs.

Answer (score 0):

We have explicit wait conditions to wait for the elements to be loaded.
Remove the explicit, fluent, implicit wait conditions if you've in your code.

You don't need to implement this I think it is already there in Selenium that is why we've so many conditions for explicit wait like "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath")));"

Comment: here I'm trying not to wait for transition time of next page to reflect.